# Last whitespace remains in data post looping through and replacing

Tags: python, replace, whitespace

I've ran into a bit of a mind boggling issue, I'm trying to remove all whitespace for data *keyword.txt* and keeping only the string of letters. But after looping through and replacing each whitespace to an empty field a new line is still seen in the output, and therefore messing up another output.

I'm not sure what to make of this.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

kf = open ('keyword.txt', 'r')
sl = open ('syslog.txt', 'r')

keywordList = []

for keyword in kf:
    keyword = keyword.replace('\n', "")
    keywordList.append(keyword)
    print keyword

for string in sl:
    for keyword in keywordList:
        if keyword in string:
            print "**"+keyword+"**"
```

A sample of the output this produces:

```
**anacron**
****
**anacron**
****
**CRON**
****
```

You can see that the `****` appears in lines due to it recognising an empty space as a keyword. That's the problem...

*keyword.txt*

```
NetworkManager
avahi-daemon
dnsmasq
dbus
kernel
dhclient
CRON
bluetoothd
failsafe
modem-manager
udev-configure-printer
modem-manager
polkitd
anacron
acpid
rt-kit daemon
goa
AptDaemon
AptDaemon.PackageKit
AptDaemon.Worker
python
```

Comment: Is there an extra blank line between keyword lines in your file?

Comment: Can you give us some of keyword.txt and syslog.txt? It seems to me that you might have blank lines in keyword.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the whitespace isn't being grabbed as part of each word but rather as an individual word.

Try reading in the files like this

```
kf = [x.strip() for x in open('keyword.txt', 'r') if not x.strip() == '']
```

Then loop through the list like you are doing.

Other variations include

```
kf = [x.strip() for x in open('keyword.txt', 'r') if x.strip() != '']

kf = [x.strip() for x in open('keyword.txt', 'r') if x.strip()]
```

as mentioned in the comments

Comment: You can replace `if x.strip() is not ''` with `if x.strip()`.

Comment: Oh awesome.  I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: `0`, `None`, and empty sequences or mappings [evaluate to `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

Comment: @RNikoopour In fact, you should not use `is` to compare strings—whether equal strings are always the same object or not is an implementation detail. In general, you probably only want `is` if you're [comparing Enum members](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons) or checking for singletons like `None`.

Comment: Oh for sure.  I know I've had issues using `is` in string comparisons.  I'll change it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Not only sequences, but containers in general. So `list`s, `string`s, and `bytes`, yes, but also things like `dict`s and `deque`s.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 
Is that better?

Comment: This does in fact work, but I don't understand what is happening. How is the first x.strip() recognised if x isn't even assigned yet? I'm new to python and I don't understand this.

Comment: This is a list comprehension. It follows a [certain syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: @Joanna This is called a list comprehension.  It goes through each item in the list `for x in ...` then trys the conditional `if x.strip...` if the conditional evaluates to true it then appends it to a new list

Comment: @RN, you actually don't need the ` == ''` at all. Just do `if x.strip()]`. If `x.strip()` has characters in it, it will evaluate to `True`.

Comment: @Joanna I believe it's meant to read more like a sentence: “the stripped form of `x` for every `x` in `open(...)` if the stripped form of `x` is truey.”

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  I just like being explicit to make the code easier to read.  `if x.strip() == ''` is explicit and doesn't require knowledge of the inner workings of Python in order to understand it.

Comment: @RNikoopour In general, use `foo != bar` instead of `not foo == bar` (and `foo not in bar` instead of `not foo in bar`, and `foo is not bar` instead of `not foo is bar`); in this case, just use `if x.strip()`. Explicit is better than implicit, yes, but anyone who knows Python fairly well will know about this—if they don't, they should learn.

Comment: I appreciate the explicitness and all the other answers, thank you guys!

Comment: @RNikoopour [The official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) says to use `is not` rather than `not ... is`—I think it's safe to assume that extends to `!=` and `not ... ==`. It _also_ says to check the truthiness of sequences directly rather than using `len()`—this probably also extends to checking against empty sequences.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Hey!  I really appreciate you linking me the style guide.  I didn't know that existed! (This is not sarcasm.  I want to make that clear cuz it reads like saracsm.)

Answer (score 0):

Your KeywordList may contain duplicate keywords. Try using a `set` instead:

```
keywords = set()

for keyword in kf:
    keyword = keyword.replace('\n', "")
    keywords.add(keyword)
    print keyword

for string in sl:
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in string:
            print "**"+keyword+"**"
```

I tried it with this data and it worked...

```
kf = ['anacron\n','anacron\n','CRON\n']
sl = ['a sentence with anacron\n','another sentence\n', 'one more\n', 'anacron\n','finally\n','one with CRON\n']
```